# How to avoid changing the address in the address bar in PHP

Tags: php, redirect

I have one problem with the address bar (in the browser).
The homepage url of my website looks like this: `http://localhost/Website/index.php`

If I write `.../Website/home.php` it loads the the `home.php` page. I think it is not safe if anyone can go to any of the webpage they want if know its address. I want to block the automatic url redirection in the address bar. Please anyone help me make so that if someone write the `.../home.php` address it redirects the browser to `index.php` as the default page.

Comment: What if I want to bookmark any other page than index.php on the site?

Comment: Erm, why do you want to do this?

Comment: Not allowing users to enter URLs in their browser is good for web sites?

Answer (score 6):

The entire concept of the world wide web is that each resource (for example each web page) has a unique resource identifier (address). It is an integral part of how the internet works and you ought to conform to it, rather than avoid it.

Make sure you have a nice big link back to your home page and people will use it if they land on a different page and can't find what they want.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

in short: you cannot do that. As others mentioned, PHP is a **server side language** that means it cannot control the browser (i.e. preventing someone to change the URL). Read and follow the links in [How does PHP work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034501/how-does-php-work) to get the know the difference between server side and client side languages.

The Wikipeda articles [World Wide Web](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web), [Uniform Resource Locator (URL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_address) and [Web Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server) could also be interesting for you to get a basic understanding how the WWW works and what it is about the URLs.

But you can control which files can be accessed. There are two ways:

### Web server configuration

Most (every?) web server lets you configure rules to control which files should be accessible (aka access control). Her is an example how to do it with the [Apache web server](http://www.ducea.com/2006/07/21/apache-tips-tricks-deny-access-to-certain-file-types/).

### PHP: Front Controller

You can also do this with PHP directly (and a little web server configuration). The magic keyword her is the [Front Controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern). This is e.g. a class that acts as a single point of entry to your application. This means that every request e.g. to

```
 http://localhost/Website/home.php
```

or

```
http://localhost/Website/foo/bar.php
```

is redirected (forwarded, however you want to name it) to and processed by

```
 http://localhost/Website/index.php
```

So in the end you can and have to decide which content the user gets to see if he tries to access a certain URL.
This gives you more control over the (look of) URLs but you have to put more effort into it to configure it.

If you are interested in how this works, I suggest to have a look at the [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/) which implements this pattern.

### Open question...

Although you *can* do this, the question is whether you have to do it. If you don't want `home.php` to be accessible, why do you put it on your web server in the first place?

Or maybe you have a wrong picture of the structure of a website in your head. A **single** website consists of **multiple** pages (most times), e.g.

```
index.php   // is the main page
about.php   // is about the site or you
news.php    // contains the latest news you provide
archive.php // older news or articles
...
```

It is even wanted that a user / visitor can access these pages directly by entering the URL into the address bar or via a bookmark. This is how a website or the WWW works.

Answer (score 1):

PHP cannot do that; it is a server-side technology and so can't modify the browser's behavior. Simply don't put any other files in the directory and the browser will inform the user that no such file exists when they try to navigate to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this result even without frames. If you use javascript and ajax to dynamically load your content your url won't change.

While I never recommend this for googles sake this would be the most nice way of doing it and still work fine with PHP

Answer (score 0):

I would take Sohnee advice, but if you really want to you could create the illusion by using HTML frames.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answers posted recently.

But if you do not need `HTML` you can go into `FLASH` or `Java Applet`, once those are loaded, your URLs no longer changes.

Answer (score 0):

Use the old and good FRAMES!! Then the address won't change.

```
<frameset rows="0,*" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" border="0">
    <frame name="nothing" src="about:blank" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" framespacing="0">

    <frame name="everything" src="http://localhost/Website/index.php" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" framespacing="0">
</frameset>
```

Answer (score -2):

Weird thing to want to do but a **simple** way (and not good for anything but small sites) is to use Header(LOcation: xxxx).

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is asking how to prevent users from changing the url shown into the address bar.