# Using value passed to php by jQuery.getJSON

Tags: php, jquery

Could you handle the name "John" in php from this getJson()? Could you assign it to a php variable?

```
var output = [];
$.getJSON('DisplayMap.php',{ Name: "john" },  function(data) {
           for (var i in data.b) {
            output.push(new google.maps.LatLng(data.b[i].Ya, data.b[i].Za));
        }

  });
```

Comment: Not without HTTP/ajax. PHP runs on the server; JavaScript (in this case) runs in the browser.

Comment: are you asking how to send 'john' to php?  because other than calling a php script on the server, php is irrelevant when it comes to json. json's just an encoding/transport format for data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [decoding json value into a php variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307711/decoding-json-value-into-a-php-variable)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question. Further, for those confused by the question and who voted to close it, if you work with jQuery and PHP it's a pretty clear question (although the title is bit misleading and I will edit it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it will initiate a HTTP GET request, you can get variable in PHP as below

```
$Name = $_GET["name"];
```

Comment: Some times it is a matter of speed rather than precission. LOL

Answer (score 1):

This code will cause a GET request to `./DisplayMap.php` with a query string variable named `Name` set to the value of `john`:

```
http://www.site.com/DisplayMap.php?Name=john
```

In PHP, you would access this via `$_GET['Name']` or `$_REQUEST['Name']`.

As for the success function and what happens there, I don't really know what your system returns and it seems unrelated to your question.