# Passing form data to php with json

Tags: php, jquery, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using value passed to php by jQuery.getJSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223309/using-value-passed-to-php-by-jquery-getjson)

Hi I have this code which is passing data through:

```
var output = [];
$.getJSON(
    'DisplayMap.php',
    { runDate : $('input[name="date"]').val() },
    function(data) {
        for (var i in data.b) {
            output.push(new google.maps.LatLng(data.b[i].Ya, data.b[i].Za));
        }
    }
);
```

My question is, how would I handle that data and assign it to a php variable. Would I have to decode it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `var_dump($_GET, $_POST);`

Comment: If `$('input[name="date"]').val()` does not return JSON, you are not sending JSON (I don't see any JSON anywhere else in your code). `runDate` will contain a normal value which you access the usual way, i.e. via `$_GET`.

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to access it via

```
$_GET['runDate'];
```

---

Side note: For Google Maps API, don't access `Ya` and `Za` directly. They are not always consistently named. Instead, use `.lat` and `.lng` attribute getters

For example:

```
new google.maps.LatLng(data.b[i].lat, data.b[i].lng);
```