# How to use javascript variables in PHP

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I use a JavaScript variable as a PHP variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379224/how-can-i-use-a-javascript-variable-as-a-php-variable)

I need to use javascipt variables in PHP, how can I do that?

eg:

```
<script>
var abc = 'this is text';
</script>
```

How can I read variable `abc` in php?

Comment: you'll get an explanation over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379224/how-can-i-use-a-javascript-variable-as-a-php-variable?rq=1)

Comment: It doesn't make sense--Javascript is interpreted client-side, while PHP is interpreted server side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of doing it is to make use of a hidden text/input box.

```
<input type="text" style="display:none" id="hiddenVal" />
```

In the Javascript assign the variable to the input box.

```
<script>
function loadValues()
{
var abc = 'this is text';
document.getElementById("hiddenVal").value = abc;
//alert(document.getElementById("hiddenVal").value);
}
</script>

<body onload="loadValues();">

<form action="processing.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" style="display:none" id="hiddenVal" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
```

This is one method to allow you to use Javascript variable and post it to the backend. Alternatively if you want to display these values just remove the

> style="display:none"

on the control.

Now after the post occurred one should be able to pick up the variable using **processing.php**

```
<?php
echo $_POST["hiddenVal"];
?>
```

Very dirty way of doing this but does the trick.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure will this help you in anyway. But in this way you can use javascript in server side.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var abc= 'this is text';
<?php $abc = "<script>document.write(abc)</script>"?>   
</script>
<?php echo $abc;?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're going to want to try something with AJAX. jQuery has a nice [AJAX library](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) if doing it pure doesn't sound too appealing to you.

Answer (score 0):

The way its possible is:

redirect to a php script

or

an AJAX call to a PHP script