# How to assign JavaScript variable to PHP session variable?

Tags: javascript, php, session-variables

Here's javascript code that i have

```
  var randomnum = 30;
```

and here's PHP code

```
<?php $_SESSION['numbertoguess'] = '<script>document.write(randomnum)</script>';?>
```

But this is not passing the value
But when i am trying this code below, it works. It gives session variable that the value 'a sample thing'.

```
<?php $_SESSION['numbertoguess'] = 'a sample thing';?>
```

Comment: you are confused about the differences between client and server side programming. The way out i know is by using `AJAX`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721461/use-javascript-variable-in-php-code

Comment: You can't but this will be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338942/access-a-javascript-variable-from-php

Comment: @Shrey You want to use JS variable in PHP? Asking for clarification.

Comment: yes. Trying to give javascript value to session variable of php. HELP PLEASE!!! @RonitMukherjee

Comment: @Shrey this is not the correct approach. You should use AJAX to send data from JS to PHP and vice-versa. But I would like to know what's your complete code? What's the code to create the random number? Why you are not wryiring the logic directly in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following code. The PHP session is assigned to 30 from the Javascript value. however am not sure if this is good way for implementation.

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Html Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>

    <script>
        var randomnum = 30;
     </script>

    <?php $_SESSION['numbertoguess'] = '<script>document.write(randomnum)</script>';?>
    <?php echo $_SESSION['numbertoguess']; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access Session directly in JavaScript.

You can make a hidden field and pass it to your page and then use JavaScript to retrieve the object via document.getElementById

Comment: He wants to use JS variable in PHP. I guess you got it opposite.