# passing data ajax to same page in foreach laravel 5

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I'm newbie in ajax and laravel 5

I want pass data with ajax to foreach laravel 5 on the same page.

```
<div class="row" style="margin:3% 0px 0px 0px">
    @foreach($warung_has_kategoriwarungs['i want pass the data here'] as $Warung)
    <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-bottom:0px;min-height:100px">
        <ul class="no-padding" style="display:inline-flex;list-style-type: none;width:100%;">
            <li>
                <img class="img-circle" src="assets/gambar_contoh/foto.jpg" style="height:60px;width:60px">
            </li>
            <li style="padding:0px 0px 0px 15px ;width:100%">
                <p class="heading-toko-font" style="font-size:18px;color:#606060">{{ $Warung->Warung->nama  }}</p>
                <span class="alamat-toko-font" style="font-size:14px;color:#BCBCBC"><?php echo $Warung['Warung']['alamat']; ?></span>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>

<div style="text-align:right;">
    {!! $warung_has_kategoriwarungs['and here']->setPath('')->render(); !!}
</div>
```

and the js here (that i have no idea what i want trying for):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".kategori-warung").click(function (e) {

            //i want pass this data to foreach parameter

            var txt = $(e.target).text();
            $(".warung").fadeIn("slow").show();
            $("#nama-kategori").html(txt);
            $(".warung-semua").hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve? Do you want to feed data to the foreach from ajax?

Comment: yea, i want get some data from controller and those array need parameter that i want get from ajax when i click a link.

Comment: <li style="padding:5px 0px"><a class="kategori-warung" style="text-decoration:none;color:#5ca4a9" href="#">
                                            {{ $kategoriwarung->nama }}</a>
                                        </li>

Comment: Okay, I still don't understand the logic of it. Do you have skype or something so you can explain me more and figure out what is the proper question and answer to post here?

Comment: sorry man, i have no skypea, but thats the clear explanation from my question, maybe if theres another way to do that, you can post here  :)

Answer (score 0):

I think ajax for the same page call is not the proper solution. I think is better to use helper(Middleware) from laravel 5. This way you can make validations and redirects. Another way it will be to use only javascript to get your data and make the selects. But what are you trying to do is not right. See this post [How can I use a JavaScript variable as a PHP variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379224/how-can-i-use-a-javascript-variable-as-a-php-variable) Javascript is client side and php is server side you cannot bind them together.