# Put parameter to route in jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have this code. And i want to put id as dynamic value to parameter of route.
But i can't get the value of id i get only text id

i try these code:

```
var id = $(this).data('studentid');
var br_id = "{{ route('dep', ['student_id' =>"+id+"])}}";


$.ajax({
            url: br_id,
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) {
                $('.replace').html(data);
                //alert('hello')
            },
            error: function (jQXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(jQXHR);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        }); //end Ajax
```

and i get the below result:

```
http://localhost/library/public/dep/+id+
```

i want to show the id from select that is dynamic data and i want to put it in this parameter of route.Any solution for these?

Comment: Are you using Laravel?

Comment: @showdev yes i use laravel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 4, Pass a variable to route in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27634285/laravel-4-pass-a-variable-to-route-in-javascript) OR [Use js function variable in route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42042682/use-js-function-variable-in-route).

Comment: @Taplar so i can't use route name in jquery. only url?

Comment: Look at the duplicates showdev linked.  The issue here is that you are trying to use a variable defined on the client side, while the `{{}}` is being executed on the server side, before the client ever runs

Comment: @showdev thank you very much

Comment: @Taplar ok i got it thank you very much

Comment: Np.  Sorry it took that long to catch that.  I'm not up on laravel syntax to know that parts were pre-processing.  I was thoroughly confused, lol

Comment: As a side note, make sure to tag things like this with the related languages/environments in the future, ;)

Comment: @Taplar lolz :)