# how to pass variable from zend framework to javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, zend-framework

how to pass variable from zf to javascript/jquery?

thanks

Comment: Unless you refine your question to address a specific issue, this is done the same way as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392470/passing-value-to-javascript-from-php and there is also a number of View Helpers for jQuery: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zendx.jquery.html

Comment: At what event you want to pass a variable to javascript function ?

Comment: Always keep this in mind: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034501/how-does-php-work

Comment: why do you need php for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can create your javascript dynamicly  by useing Headscript View Helper 
it had function like :

```
<?php $this->headScript()->captureStart() ?>
var action = '<?php echo $this->baseUrl ?>';
$('foo_form').action = action;
<?php $this->headScript()->captureEnd() ?>
```

Source : [ZF documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.headscript)

Comment: Anyone have any idea how to add attributes to the script that gets created useing this? Based on what I could make from the docs, it would be something like the following but it doesn't seem to render...

<?php $this->inlineScript()->captureStart("PREPEND", $type = 'text/javascript', $attrs = ["nonce" => "r@nd0m"]) ?>

Comment: Also tried, $this->inlineScript()->captureStart("PREPEND", 'text/javascript', ["nonce" => "r@nd0m"])

Comment: Ugh.  It looks like defining captureStart params might only exist for headScripts.  That is just silly.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$this->view->foo = $foo;
?>
```

In your view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var foo = <?=Zend_Json::encode($this->foo)?>;
</script>
```

Comment: i want to pass variable to a js file

Comment: you can use this variable in your js file, as long as this code is executed before your js file is included

Comment: I would extract the variable to keep the js clean. In controller: `$this->view->headScript()->appendScript('var_foo='.$foo);` and js: `var foo = _foo`.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I'm sure others could benefit from this:

You could use [this extended HeadScript class](https://github.com/bogdanghervan/zf-append-var) and pass variables to JavaScript from a controller like this:

```
$this->view->headScript()->appendVar('dogName', 'Rocky')
                         ->appendVar('dogPictures', $pictures);
```

`prependVar`, `setVar` and `offsetSetVar` are also available for convenience' sake.

Comment: Hey Bogdan, I'm trying to use this but I get "Fatal error: Class 'Application\View\Helper\HeadScript' not found in /var/www/xxxx/zf2/2.2.2/library/Zend/ServiceManager/AbstractPluginManager.php on line 170". I feel like it's a setup problem, but I have HeadScript pointing to Application\View\Helper\HeadScript in getViewHelperConfig of my Application Module class. Also, I had to change the declaration to class Application_View_Helper_HeadScript extends HeadScript to get rid of the error that it couldn't find Zend\View\Helper\HeadScript. Kind of a newbie, not sure what to do next.

Comment: Finally got it to load using autoload_classmap.php, but then it said "prependVar" method does not exist. I give up on that then. Just use the method of declaring javascript variables in my view, then appending the javascript file.

Comment: I'm sorry for the trouble, @mutatron. This class is not compatible with Zend Framework 2. For anyone still using Zend Framework 1, I've added [proper installation steps](https://github.com/bogdanghervan/zf-append-var).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

class SomeController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
    public function indexAction() {
        // a file
        $this->view->headScript()->appendFile('yourJsFile.js');
        // inline script
        $message = 'hello!';
        $this->view->headScript()->appendScript("jQuery(function(){alert('$message');});");
    }
}
```

This requires that you add `echo $this->headScript()` to your view- or layout-script.

Comment: how to get $message in js file, i got error undefined variable when i try use in $message in js file

Comment: You aren't supposed to use `$message` in your JS, it's a PHP variable which gets parsed by PHP before being inserted into plain JS.

Answer (score 1):

I know this will be late answer, And I have used @chelmertz solution, but currently I got some issue with that. I am working in an complex UI application and I needed lots of php arrays and  other json objects in my external javascript files. And inclusion of my js scripts was not uniform, So each time if I need some thing from php to javascript I have to check whole things like ....

1) Am I placing appendScript() at correct position so the some.js script will find my variables defined

2) generated string which will be passed to appendScript() is a valid js syntax.
and lot more ...

There is another way I have developed for Zend Framework specially. 
I have written a detailed tutorial here 
http://rupeshpatel.wordpress.com/2012/09/21/add-json-objects-arrays-and-variables-from-php-to-javascript/

**summary:**

1) create a common view file enclosed within  tag, which checks for a property(an Array) let say $this->jsVars of a view object and defines js variables
code of this view file

```
<script>
<?php if(!empty($this->jsVars)){ ?>

<?php
foreach($this->jsVars as $var) {
if($var['type'] == 'json'){
?>
var <?php echo $var['name']?> = JSON.parse('<?php echo $var['value'];?>');
<?php } elseif($var['type'] == 'text'){ ?>
var <?php echo $var['name']?> = "<?php echo $var['value'];?>";
<?php }else{?>
var <?php echo $var['name']?> = <?php echo $var['value'];?>;
<?php
}}?>

<?php }?>

</script>
```

2) render this view in your layout file before `echo $this->headScript()` so all external scripts will have those js variables

```
<?php
echo $this->render('index/include_js_vars.phtml'); // rendering view

                $this->headScript()->prependFile(JS_BASE_URL.'/jquery-1.7.2.min.js');
$this->headScript()->appendFile(JS_BASE_URL.'/jquery.blockUI.js');
$this->headScript()->appendFile(JS_BASE_URL.'/commonJS.js');
$this->headScript()->appendFile('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js');

                echo $this->headScript();
?>
```

3) append php arrays or json objects to $this->view->jsVars like

// in your action method

```
$test = array('mango','orange','banana');
$this->view->jsVars[] = array('name'=>'test','type'=>'json','value'=>json_encode($test));
```

now `test` will be defined in any of your script files as an array, No matter at what instance you have included your js file.

Answer (score 0):

I came here and tried all the answers but non of them helped me, so what I ended up doing was the next (maybe it's too late, but could be helpful for someone else):

Inside the controller where you want to pass the variable to js:

```
public function someAction()
{
    $var = array(
        'test' => 'phpVar',
        'test2' => 'phpVar2'
    );

    $this->view->jsVar = $var;
}
```

Now in your layout, inside head tag, and before load any other script do this:

```
$this->headScript()->appendScript('var phpVars='.json_encode($this->jsVar));
```

Finally in your js file, you would be able to access the variable phpVars:

```
console.log(phpVars);
```

you could see in the console:

```
Object {test: "phpVar", test2: "phpVar2"}
```

being able to access each variable like `phpVars.test` and `phpVars.test2`

Now you can pass variables from your controller to js files everytime you want.