# PHP e-mail form-enable it locally

Tags: php, html, forms, email, localhost

My code is this:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$to = "email@example.com"; // this is your Email address
$from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$subject = "Form submission";
$subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
$message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
$message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

$headers = "From:" . $from;
$headers2 = "From:" . $to;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
// You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Form submission</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="post">
First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name"><br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
Message:<br><textarea rows="5" name="message" cols="30"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I got it off of another question for a php email form and i want to test it locally. How do i do this?

I do eventually plan to publish it in the site i'm working on for a friend.

Comment: You mean... how do you set up a web server that will serve PHP pages?

Comment: @Mike, Err, i don't know. Is that necessary? I don't know how PHP works

Comment: You really need to do some research then if you don't know how PHP works. You will need a web server (e.g. Apache), a mail server and PHP installed and configured on your computer to test it. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034501/how-does-php-work and Google is your friend for anything else not covered there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a smtp mail server authentication via phpmailer or swiftmailer. Then your form will deliver to target address. For more information: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer